# Unable to add AutoLayout constraints to elements in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I've got a `UITableView` and a `UITableViewCell` inside it. I'm trying to add constraints to a `UILabel` inside said cell, but all of the options are greyed out for me. **There are currently no constraints on anything in the cell.** I can add constraints through `Editor>Resolve Auto Layout Issues>Add Missing Constraints`, but when I do that and run my app I get a whole bunch of constraint errors in the log.

[image: Screenshot of Problems]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the tableViewCell defined as Style = Custom ?

Comment: No, it's defined as Right Detail. I figure that's probably why it's rejecting adding constraints.

Comment: change to custom and you would be able to add constraints

Comment: And then if I'm not mistaken, I have to specifically add `UILabels` to get the detail on the cell? It doesn't matter anyway because I added the 'Item Name' label programmatically and the problems I was having fixed themselves. Still, this is technically the correct answer for this problem so I'll mark it as solved.